# How to count the numbers in values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, numbers

I'm trying to count the amount of values that contain numbers that show up in the values of dictionary entries, and then put them in a list. So for example:

```
some_dictionary = {'FIRST' : ['a', '1', 'b', '2'], 
                   'SECOND' : ['c', 'd', '3', 'e'], 
                   'THIRD' : ['4', '5', 'f', 'g6']}

some_dictionary_values = [2, 1, 3]
```

So far I have:

```
for key, value in some_dictionary.items():
    for string in value:
        if any(char.isdigit() for char in string):
            amount_of_numbers.append(string)
```

but this seems like a really roundabout way of doing it. I'd like to know if I'm on the right track or if there's an easier way of going about this.

edit: I guess my question wasn't very clear. Let me give another example:

```
dictionary = {'ONE' : ['abc', '123', 'def']
              'TWO' : ['happy', '42', 't4']
              'THREE' : ['word2', 'word', 'words']}
```

So the key 'ONE' has the values 'abc', '123', and 'def'. Of these values, only one of them contains a number, so in the list this would show up as 1.
The key 'TWO' has two values which contain numbers, '42' and 't4'.
The key 'THREE' has one value which contains a number, 'word2'.

Therefore the final list will be:

```
final_list = [1, 2, 1]
```

I hope that made my problem clearer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, each item in your output list corresponds to one dictionary entry? If so, that's problematic because dicts are unordered so you won't know which list item corresponds to which dict entry.

Comment: Is there a way to refer them to a string? For example: string = 'Today is nice.' and then have each word in the string be a different key in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edited Answer***

```
amount_of_numbers = {}
for key, value in some_dictionary.items():
    amount_of_numbers[key] = len ([string for string in value if all(char.isdigit() for char in string) ])
print amount_of_numbers
{'SECOND': 1, 'THIRD': 2, 'FIRST': 2}
```

***Original Answer***

Here you go:

```
some_dictionary = {'FIRST' : ['a', '1', 'b', '2'], 
                   'SECOND' : ['c', 'd', '3', 'e'], 
                   'THIRD' : ['4', '5', 'f', 'g6']}

amount_of_numbers = []

for value in some_dictionary.values():
    amount_of_numbers += [string for string in value if all(char.isdigit() for char in string)]

print amount_of_numbers
['3', '4', '5', '1', '2']
```

Note that your current implementation is incorrect, it includes `g6` also in the output, even though it is not a number

Comment: Ah okay I guess I wasn't clear in what I was asking. What I meant was the final list is the # of times a number showed up in the value for the key.

Comment: @learningpython check edits. Since a normal dictionary does not have its keys in order, I think a dictionary as an output is much more suitable.

Comment: No I want to include 'g6' because it CONTAINS a number.

Comment: Okay I'm going through your edited answer but I still want the 'g6' in the answer. Would replacing all with any work?

Comment: No, I mean `{'SECOND': 1, 'THIRD': 2, 'FIRST': 2}` which is there in my answer now. Also, if that helps, don't forget to accept :)

Comment: I meant all and any for the all(char.isdigit() part

Comment: Did you notice that you run a chance of overloading Python __string__ module?

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner utilizes the fact that in arithmetical expressions boolean behaves as integer

```
{key: sum(any(c.isdigit() for c in word) for word in value) 
    for key, value in some_dictionary.iteritems()}
```